# Serialize/deserialize between MONO-client and ASP.NET server - possible or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, mono

I have different objects I would like to be able to **load and save on a ASP.NET (IIS webserver)** from my MONO client. So I have made them as Class objects.

As example I have [Score] which I will be using for producing a hiscore on a server.

**Score.cs**

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
[System.Serializable]
public class Score
{
    public long Total;
    public string Name;
    public Score(){}
    public Score(string name, long total)
    {
        Total = total;
        Name = name;
    }

}
```

This code I want to use as data structure (n-tier architecture) in both MONO as clientside structure and in my ASP.NET server I use it as serverside object too.

What I do is that I want to build a list-array like this:

```
List<Score> hiscores = new List<Score>();
hiscores.add (new Score("Player 1", 10000));
hiscores.add (new Score("Player 2", 20000));
hiscores.add (new Score("Player 3", 30000));
hiscores.add (new Score("Player 4", 40000));
```

... then I want to serialize it into a bytearray so I can POST it as binaryfile:

```
MemoryStream membytes = new MemoryStream(); 
BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
binFormatter.Serialize(membytes, hiscores );
```

...

BUT - on the webserver, in ASP.NET/C# I get an error 500 telling me that it cannot load the assemble for deserializing the data???

HUH?! I've read someone suggesting to make the assemble as external?  and then link it on both platforms, is that possible in my situation or am I on the wrong path somehow?

I can easily transfer a simle bytearray with values from 0x00 to 0xff to my ASP.NET and save it. But once I start using serialize/deserialize on my List objects and transfer them into a Byte[] things messes up?

**QUESTION**
Is deserialization not possible if the serializer isnt made on the same platform?

is it possible to place the dataobjects (business objects) in a DLL project and then link/use this on both platforms and that way gaining the same assemble value?

Comment: Binary serialization should only be used as a transport medium between different parts *of the same program*, not between systems, and not as a storage format. Too much version information is bundled up for the format to survive even a minor software upgrade, let alone being given to a completely different system altogether.

Comment: Perhaps I should write my own object->binary converter and use that on both sides? I have a LOT of custom gameobjects and as they need to get loaded from the server and stored back, I would rather avoid XML etc. as much as possible. I fear the XML version would become waaaay too big and generate too much traffic both ways.

Comment: Try protobuf then - http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

Comment: Very interesting! might just be what I need. thanks.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, please post your response as answer. I think that solves my problem.

Comment: Better to accept the answer by CodeInChaos, since he has already mentioned protobuf.

Comment: @Lasse yes you are right. Havent testet the thing yet, as I am trying to make a seperate storage-project with the embedded Score.cs class and other functions to handle it. then I will try to embed this in both platforms as DLL.

Comment: I've actually got it to work now. without any external libraries! Just build my own BusinessObject in a seperate project as a DLL, and placed it in both projects. Works perfectly.

Comment: I've posted my findings now as an answer for others who might be in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

[BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) produces a non-interoperable binary format. Use it only if both the client and the server run the same version of the CLR. Otherwise you could use an interoperable format such as XML ([`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)) or JSON ([`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)) to communicate between your client and server.

Comment: Cant go with XML or JSON as its C# and rather big datastructures for levelmaps etc. so I need to keep the data at a minimum for download and upload - got any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your big mistake is using `BinaryFormatter` for this. This has many issues.

1. You should trust the data you deserialize. This is rarely the case in client-server applications.
2. It uses some internal format, and I'm not sure how compatible that is between different versions of .net or even between .net and mono. Use a serializer with a well defined format.

Good alternatives for this use-case are Json or Xml serializers. Personally usually use Json.net, but .net has also a built in Json serializier.

`BinaryFormatter` might be the right choice if you serialize a complex object graph, don't need versioning and only read it back on the same system, so you can trust the data. And even in that scenario I'd only use it because I know no better alternative, not because I like `BinaryFormatter`.

---

Since you now stated that you transfer a lot of data I'd look into protobuf-net. It's a binary serializer that is very fast and produces compact data. But you should annotate all your properties with numeric IDs. It's author Marc Gravell is active here on SO, so you can expect good support.

Comment: I do trust the data, as I write both parts, both client and server. But the client uses Mono framework and the data is large amount game data, so using XML would hurt performance quite a bit. The game runs in the client, but all leveldata, prefs, AI etc. runs on the server, so I need to be able to download data to objects quickly and then put the moves back up to the server. Not real time. Just efficient.

Comment: Writing the client is not enough. Controlling the computer it is running on is the issue you don't want a rogue client to be able to hack your server.

Comment: If performance is the issue look into proto-buf. It requires more configuration that most other serializers, but it's very fast and the data is compact. I assumed that you were only transmitting the highscore -- which is usually rather small.

Comment: regarding cheaters/hackers - yes, I am aware of that part. Thats not my question and I dont think XML nor JSON would do that any different?

Comment: Of course it would be different. Json/Xml can send you invalid data, but if the deserializer is any good they won't allow the attacker to execute code. Most other serializers go through public properties, require annotations,... BinarySerializer can simply write evil stuff into your private fields, instantiate arbitrary types,... Perhaps it's possible to control it, but I don't know how.

Comment: No worries, I am paranoid about data by default. :o) I only need to get the data from my binary buffer into objects, then I will do the validation.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure if the transfer between the buffer and your objects is safe with binary formatter.

Comment: Okay? I use IP, session among other things to identify the sender/receiver server-side. But anyways, the question is still about how to put objects into a bytestream and upload it to the server with serialization somehow.

Answer (score 1):

**Posting my own answer as I actually managed to get it working without extras**

First of all, thanks for all the great suggestions for extra libraries, but my initial question was about if it was possible to make MONO and ASP.NET communicate through serialization.

**The answer is: YES!**

All I had to to was to build a seperate Class-project (DLL) where I put all the datastructures I need to serialize.

Then make it a reference on both platforms and voila, same DLL = same assembly and both platforms agrees that serialization and deserialization is no problem.

**Note on binary result/traffic/space**

I agree, the binary data seems to be a bit "overkill" compared to some of the other suggested plugins/libraries in here. But it IS possible without any extra libs.

That was my initial goal.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Mike Talbot's Silverlight Serializer  http://whydoidoit.com/2010/04/08/silverlight-serialization/
which is very lightweight and should work with both MONO and .NET

Comment: interesting too, but I stumpled upon this one: "SilverlightSerializer is a binary serializer that works in .NET and Silverlight, allowing you to move your objects between the two instances or store and retrieve them locally in either." - I need to move between a client and a server, from MONO to NET and back?