# How to mix Pinvoke WriteFile and BinaryFormatter usage of the same FileStream?

Tags: c#, file-io, pinvoke, filestream

I want to use WriteFile to write big (~500mb) multidimensional array into file (because BinaryFormatter is very slow at writing big stuff and there is no other way in .Net framework to write multidimensiona byte arrays, only single bytes or single-dimensional arrays, and doing for loop and writing byte by byte is slow).

However, turns out, this is forbidden:

```
IOException
The OS handle's position is not what FileStream expected. Do not use a handle simultaneously in one FileStream and in Win32 code or another FileStream. This may cause data loss.
```

Is there any way around this, aside from re-opening the file stream each time I want to write using BinaryFormatter after I wrote using WriteFile?

Comment: Nice exception.  Ultimately it is pointless to use WriteFile(), FileStream.Write() already pinvokes it.  Writing half a gigabyte of file data is only fast on a 64-bit operating system with enough RAM so everything is buffered by the file system cache before it is (slowly) written to the disk.  Not hard to come by.

Comment: I know it's faster, both on 64 and 32, I tested it. Basically, problem is not in size, but in the fact that Write() can only write single-dimensional arrays, but I am operating multi-dimensional arrays, and due to C# limitations I cannot cast byte[,,] to byte[]. So, in order to write multidimensional array, I have to do a for loop and write byte by byte, which is much slower. It has nothing to do with hard drive cache - modern HDDs can do I/O at 100MB/s and SSD's can reach around 450 MB/s.

Comment: You mean, in for loop write and read each single dimension? This doesnt fix my problem at all. If my array is 1024x1024x1024 I'm still reading only one kilobyte at a time.

Comment: That's plenty, it reduces the extra overhead of checking for errors in FileStream.Write() by 3 orders of magnitude.

Comment: Anyways, its not the point. It doesnt solve the problem (even if it somehow makes it less of a problem it's not a solution).

Answer (score 0):

*(I understand this question has been abandoned and will be deleted soon.)*

Firstly, `WriteFile` and `BinaryFormatter` just don't mix. `WriteFile` assumes you know the file format, i.e. the interpretation of the bytes that are written to the file. `BinaryFormatter` is a serializer, based on a file format that is internal to Microsoft .NET implementation (some would say proprietary, even though the information can be found online). [As a consequence, you cannot even pass a file serialized by `BinaryFormatter` between Microsoft .NET and Mono C#.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6809665/)

Based on OP's description, it is clear that OP should not have used `BinaryFormatter` in the first place. Otherwise OP would be solely responsible for the loss (unrecoverability) of such data.

As Hans Passant commented, the performance of `FileStream.Write` should be able to match the Win32 call to `WriteFile`, asymptotically speaking. What this means is that the time overhead for *each call* can be modeled as `alpha * numberOfBytesWritten + beta`, where `beta` is the pure constant overhead per call. One can make this overhead relatively negligible by increasing the number of bytes written per call.

Given that we cannot directly pass a multidimensional C# array into `WriteFile`, here is the suggestion. Based on OP's comment, it is assumed the multidimensional array will have size `byte[1024, 1024, 1024]`.

- First, allocate a temporary 1D array of sufficient size. Typical recommendations range from 4KB to several MB, but that is only an optimization detail. For this example, we use 1MB = `byte[1048576]` because it nicely divides the total array size.
- Then, we write a top-level for-loop over the outermost dimension.
- In the next step, we use the [`System.Array.Copy` utility function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to copy the `1024 x 1024` bytes from the innermost two dimensions into the temporary 1D array. This relies on C# specification on multidimensional arrays, as documented on the `System.Array.Copy` function:

> When copying between multidimensional arrays, the array behaves like a long one-dimensional array, where the rows (or columns) are conceptually laid end-to-end.

- Once copied into the temporary 1D array, it can be written out to `FileStream.Write`.